# Javascript to change this.style.backgroundImage

Tags: javascript

Given the following code, how would I finish `tileClick()` in order to change the clicked image from "tileBack.jpg" to instead show the image that was assigned to that specific `div` in `shuffleDeck()` ? What I mean is, the `tileClick()` function is supposed to take a tile that is currently showing the tileBack image, and, when clicked, show the image that is on the "reverse side" of that tile.

So far, you can see how I've tried to target the specific tile being clicked, though I'm uncertain `this.` is being used correctly here. On the other side of that statement, I've tried to do things like `= "../img/tile_"+tiles[i]+".png";` but obviously the issue there is that `i` does not exist within that function's scope. My problem is that I can't figure out how to restructure my code so that I can access the image that was previously assigned to a given `div`. For reference, the "other side" of the tiles are named as "tile_##.png" where '##' is a 2-digit number (01-12).

I am very new to JS and programming in general, so please keep your answers simple enough for me to understand and implement.

```
var deck = [];
var tiles = [];
var sources = [ "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" ];
var images = [];

const WIDTH = 100;
const HEIGHT = 100;
const NUMTILES = 24;

loadImages();
buildDeck();
shuffleDeck(7);
printDeck();

function loadImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        images[i] = "../img/tile_"+sources[i]+".png";
    }
}

function buildDeck() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < sources.length; j++) {
            var tempTile = {};
            tempTile.val = sources[j];
            tempTile.img = images[j];
            deck.push(tempTile);
        }
    }
}

function shuffleDeck (numTimes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < deck.length; j++) {
            var tempTile = deck[j];
            var randI = j;
            while ( randI == j ) {
                randI = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length );
            }
            deck[j] = deck[randI];
            deck[randI] = tempTile;
        }
    }
}

function printDeck() {
    for (var i = 0; i < NUMTILES; i++) {
        tiles[i] = document.getElementById("tile"+i);
        console.log(deck[i].img);
        tiles[i].style.backgroundImage = "../img/tileBack.jpg";
    }
}

function tileClick() {
    document.querySelector(".tile").addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
          this.style.backgroundImage = 
    });
}
```

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Leor6jqr/

Comment: `I am very new to JS and programming in general` and you've written that neat piece of code? Way to go!

Comment: Could you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to experiment with?

Comment: @howderek Yes, I'll make the JS fiddle right now.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky To be fair, it took me most of my first semester at school to get this far :)

Comment: @howderek The link is at the bottom of the main post. I've never used JS Fiddle before, so please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: It's okay, I think I figured it out without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the event listener and `bind` the index to the calling event in your Deck printing.

```js
function printDeck() {
    for (var i = 0; i < NUMTILES; i++) {
        tiles[i] = document.getElementById("tile"+i);
        console.log(deck[i].img);
        tiles[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/tileBack.jpg')";
        tiles[i].addEventListener("mousedown", tileClick.bind(this, i));
    }
}

//  *** Game Functions *** //

function tileClick(index) {
    console.log('img', event, index, deck[index].img);
    tiles[index].style.backgroundImage = "url('"+deck[index].img+"')";
}
```

Comment: [@Gerald](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4455537/gerald-christie) This is a simplistic solution to your question, but will put you an track to understanding how to bind the values to your method call. It would have been just as easy to bind the image path.  Inspect the `event` in the console to see what was clicked `event.target`. You may also want to inspect the value of `this` to understand what is being bound.

Comment: This isn't something I've learned how to do, but I'm certainly willing to learn. If I copy and paste your code as is, when I click on a tile the Chrome console prints `MouseEvent {dataTransfer: null, which: 1, toElement: div#tile17.tile, fromElement: null, y: 324…} 17 ../img/tile_02.png` (Where `tile_02.png` depends on which tile I click), which seems to indicate that the correct array index is being referenced, but the tile remains showing the tileBack.jpg image.

Comment: Not sure the links of your images are correct.  You may want to double check. That is why I included the debug for you.

Comment: Try my edits in the code again. Did not notice your `backgroundImage` [values did not specify url](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp).

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what was needed. I was trying to get here from your original code, but I've been staring at this all day and am going a little cross-eyed. Your responses are very much appreciated. I'm going to have to look into `bind` some more to make sure I fully understand this, but I think I get it well enough to continue working.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I think this is what you want:

```
function tileClick() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".tile");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        elems[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '#933';
        });
    }
}

tileClick();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/g68b73Lv/

But, just telling you how to do it doesn't help you know what's wrong.

The problem with your function wasn't with `this` it was with how you used `querySelector`.

`querySelector` only returns the first element that matches your search. `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` with all of the matches, which you can just iterate through

Comment: I understand my mistake with `querySelector`, so thank you for that. However, I still don't understand how to get the code to show a specific image when the tile is clicked. Where your code says `this.style.backgroundColor = '#933';` I need it to say `this.style.backgroundImage = 'image that was stored into this array index during the shuffleDeck() call'`. If that makes sense? I apologize if I'm not explaining myself well.

Comment: You'll want to assign the eventListener when you are creating the elements in `printDeck` if you want them to have dynamic content